# Strange Password Encryption issue C++ where any similar password will work,

Tags: c++, hash, passwords

I have an issue that I can't figure out, though I've probably looked at it for too long to see what it is.

I store in a database table 2 password fields, one called PasswordHash (nvarchar(MAX)) and one PasswordSalt(uniqueidentifier) along with other user fields.

When the user first tries to long on they are prompted for a password, this is written into the database with the following SQLCommand: -

```
    asSQLCommand = "UPDATE YCR_User_Names SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES(\'SHA2_512',\'";
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + editPassword->Text;
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + "\' + CAST(N\'";
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + Sysutils::GUIDToString(gSalt);
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + "\' AS NVARCHAR(36))) WHERE ID = ";
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + sqlGetUser->FieldByName("ID")->AsInteger;
```

i.e. it takes their password, attaches a randomly generated PasswordSalt then then encrypts the lot.

When it comes to them signing on, I use the following SQL to check to see if the password matches.

```
    asSQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM YCR_User_Names WHERE PasswordHash = HASHBYTES(\'SHA2_512',\'";
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + editPassword->Text;
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + "\' + CAST(N\'";
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + sqlGetUser->FieldByName("PasswordSalt")->AsVariant;
    asSQLCommand = asSQLCommand + "\' AS NVARCHAR(36)))";
```

As you can see (hopefully) it checks to see if encrypting the same password with the same salt is valid.

The problem is, lets say the password is "FredFlintstone" then as long as the first two characters are correct (Fr) then it's always accepted.

Can you see where I've made a mistake?

Comment: The part where someone can log in as a diferent user by typing `') OR 1 = 1 OR ('' = '` (I think) as their password is a mistake, but it's not the same mistake you're asking about.

Comment: Not what you are asking but don't you have a SQL injection vulnerablity? Composing SQL from string operations is not recommended.

Comment: I assume you already checked what the actual SQL command is?

Comment: @john This reminds me of [xkcd.com/327](https://xkcd.com/327/). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the password i was testing with was using ! and it worked up until I hit the ! character. My FredFlintstone example actually worked.

I'm not too worried about the data itself, it's more there to stop the 8 people that use it from dicking around as somebody else, no sensitive data is stored.